# Is there a plug and play solution to hookup a donate button into React?

Tags: reactjs, paypal, square

I want to add a donate button to my hobby website that allows users to donate any amount of money they wanted in a sort of help pay for servers/coffee kind of way. I was surprised to find a lot of solutions were quite involved to setup properly. Are there any good plug and play solutions?

Answer (score 1):

An HTML donation button from [paypal.com/buttons](https://www.paypal.com/buttons/) will do fine.

Comment: And Venmo has similar links and QR codes.